# Firefox mobile install problem on HTC wildfire

Tags: installation, htc-wildfire, firefox-for-android

I tried to install firefox mobile edition on HTC wildfire (Indian edition) but it fails 
anyone faced the same problem or any workaround available to install

Comment: Which way did you install Firefox? There are currently two ways to get and install it, either from the Android Market at http://www.appbrain.com/app/mozilla-firefox-web-browser/org.mozilla.firefox or as a download from Mozilla themselves that you can then "side-load" onto your device from http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/mobile/download/ Also can you let us know how the install failed. Did you get any error messages?

Comment: I'm afraid you may simply be out of luck for the time being.  The Wildfire is not on the [list of supported devices](https://www.mozilla.com/en-US/mobile/platforms/)

Answer (score 2):

*Credit to Matt H's comment for pointing me the right way.*

If you follow through to the [System Requirements page on their wiki](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/Platforms/Android#System_Requirements), the HTC Wildfire is specifically called out as an unsupported device as it has an ARMv6 based processor; Firefox Mobile currently requires an ARMv7 compatible processor.

They do have an [experimental build for ARMv6 based devices](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/Platforms/Android#ARMv6_.28experimental.29), which you can [download here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/Platforms/Android#ARMv6_.28experimental.29) but according to the warning on the page, that is broken at the moment. If you keep an eye on there they may announce when it starts working.